# Force FF / chrome to ignore meta tags with greasemonkey (or otherwise)

Tags: css, cross-browser, greasemonkey

I have a to access a website that works fine with IE, but not with FF / chrome. I suspect the CSS are not being loaded in FF / chrome due to to the following meta tag:

```
<meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="...">
```

(although I'm probably off the wrong tree). Can I somehow (greasemonkey or otherwise) remove this tag and force IE behavior? I've tryed the user-agent add-on, as well as trying the following GM script:

```
var microsoft = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

while(microsoft.length > 0) { 
  microsoft[0].parentNode.removeChild(microsoft[0]);
}
```

But to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you suspect that it's that tag?

Comment: @KevinJohnson - I't seems that's the only thing related to browser dependency - It's not some minor CSS glitch - the entire page is different.

Comment: That tag is not the cause.  If you examine the page's HTML, JS, and CSS carefully, you will see that it uses Micros**t-proprietary code throughout. ... Greasemonkey can still fix it, but it will require a lot of little tweaks (usually).

Comment: @BrockAdams - Care to mention some of these tags by name? An example of such and / or a greasemonkey fix would be much appreciated.

Comment: The tags are legion, consult any browser-compatibility table.  The details and the fix(es) are **extremely page-specific**, there is no magic bullet except the one I employ (boycott such sites with prejudice). ... For anything more specific link to the page in question (or zip of said page's code).

Answer (score 2):

I've done some [research](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t97952-can-i-remove-this-meta-tag.html) and it seems that the tag isn't going to change how the page displays, have you tried removing the tag and seeing what happens? After all, programming is about tinkering :)

Comment: I can't really - this isn't my page - I'm only the "customer" as it were. I should also note this is an .aspx page - perhaps different pages are being loaded behind the scenes?

Comment: Try downloading the HTML to your hard-drive, as a .html file. You should be able to open that in different browsers, and even remove the tag to test.

Comment: you can also remove the tag in the chrome code inspector (or similar) straight on the live page to see the effect...

Comment: @PeterVR Do you think chrome would re-render the page just because a `meta` tag disappeared?

Comment: @nbubis did this help you at all?

Comment: Not quite - I think Brock Adams comment was to the point - that is, my question wasn't a very good one, and that I should't get my hopes up.